# Building layout from database in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a boot strap layout, that build some menus using "ul" and "li"

```
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="icon-x"></i>
      <span>Some action</span>
    </a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" >
      <i class="icon-y"></i>
      <span>Group action</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="/subs1"> Submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/subs2"> Submenu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
....
```

This is ok, but I will build this structure using data from the database tables.
I create a helper to load data from the database and build this menu. But this is causing several "select" commands to the server for every page rebuild.

My question is, how you guys are doing this?

UPDATE:

this is my helper code (note my actual code is a little more complex):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def build_main_menu
    menus = Menu.all(:conditions => "root_id is null")
    menus.map do |m|
      content_tag :li do
        content_tag :a, :href => m.url do
          concat(content_tag(:i, :class => m.icone) do end)
          concat(content_tag(:span, m.legenda))
        end
      end
    end.join("\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

and the erb layout:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <%= build_main_menu %>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show your helper, and erb or template code?

Comment: Ok, just updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@menus ||= Menu.all(:conditions => "root_id is null")
```

This will cache your query in a var, but I think you should not be worried with log saying you are hitting database severals times, because Rails already caches queries, your log should be saying something with CACHE.

Suggestions, extract that function to model and use where instead of all, you will be lazy loading resources with where

```
class Menu
  scope :without_root, where('root_id is null')
```

And in your helper

```
@menus ||= Menu.without_root
```

I think my second paragraph applies just when you use where.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<%= link_to  controllers_path do %>
    Some Action <i class="icon-x"></i>
<% end %>
```